# .NET Antialias not working on server

Tags: asp.net, bitmap, gdi, system.drawing, antialiasing

I have an ASP.NET web application that display some images. For thumbnail display, I have to resize them. Here is my code:

```
        var newImage = new Bitmap(sourceImage, width, height);
        var g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage);
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        g.DrawImage(newImage, 0, 0, newImage.Width, newImage.Height);
        newImage.Save(path,GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg), myEncoderParameters);
```

Everything looks ok if I run in LOCALHOST. However, when I publish on server, the image quality is very poor and broken.
As Microsoft documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.smoothingmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the System.Drawing namespace is not support for some platform, but seems like that's not my case (I'm not very sure).
 This is my server system specification: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByVZ1.jpg (Please follow the link, I do not have enough reputation to post image).

Can anyone please help me with this. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer by myself. The problem is when I call

```
g.DrawImage(newImage, 0, 0, newImage.Width, newImage.Height);
```

It will draw an resized image into itself, that is the object:

```
 new Bitmap(sourceImage, width, height));
```

so all the settings of the graphic object is not affected. The resize functioned actually at the above line of code.
The correct solution should be:

```
g.DrawImage(sourceImage, 0, 0, newImage.Width, newImage.Height);
```

And everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your `Graphics` settings.

```
g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
```

I'm thinking `CompositingQuality.Default` may be different between your two machines.

[`Graphics.CompositingQuality` Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.compositingquality%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @dat1991 Is your encoder (as returned by `GetEncoder(...)`) potentially different on the two machines? Heavy JPEG compression could result in "very poor and broken" image quality.

Comment: this is my function:
private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
        {
            var codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();

            return codecs.FirstOrDefault(codec => codec.FormatID == format.Guid);
        }
Also, the problem only occur when resize to small size image ( i.e. 200px width). When I resize to larger size, the image still looks good.